# SQL-ex.ru #26 Selecing average from two tables

Tags: sql, join, union

I had a question about a sql query on the website http://www.sql-ex.ru/. The query asks for 
:

> Define the average price of the PCs and laptops produced by maker A.

The database schema is as follows:

```
Product(maker, model, type)
PC(code, model, speed, ram, hd, cd, price)
Laptop(code, model, speed, ram, hd, screen, price)
Printer(code, model, color, type, price)
```

I wrote my query as:

```
SELECT AVG(t.k) AS Avg_Price
FROM
  (SELECT AVG(A.price) AS k
    FROM PC A 
  JOIN Product B ON(A.model=B.model)
  WHERE B.maker='A'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT AVG(C.price) AS k
     FROM Laptop C
  JOIN PRODUCT D ON(C.model=D.model)
  WHERE D.maker='A') AS t
```

The problem is that it does not return the correct answer. The average returned is much higher than expected. Is the way the average is calculated wrong? How do I change the query so that it returns the expected answer? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're averaging pc prices and laptop prices separately, then averaging the averages together.  Your query was good except that you shouldn't have averaged the prices in the sub queries.  simply return the prices in the sub queries and average at the top level:

```
select
    AVG( Price ) Avg_Price
from
(
    (
        select
            pc.Price
        from
            PC pc
            join Produt prod
             on pc.Model = prod.Model
        where
            prod.Maker = 'A'
    )
    union all
    (
        select
            pc.Price
        from
            Laptop l
            join Produt prod
             on l.Model = prod.Model
        where
            prod.Maker = 'A'
    )
) q
```

Comment: Ah avg is not transferable as Guna said. Makes sense

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT AVG(datatable.price) FROM
(
(SELECT PC.Price FROM PC INNER JOIN Product p1 ON PC.model=P1.model     
     WHERE P1.maker='A') 
UNION ALL 
(SELECT Laptop.price FROM Laptop INNER JOIN Product p2 ON 
    Laptop.model=P2.model WHERE P2.maker='A')
) datatable
```

Right.

**The result of Your query:**

> Avg_Price
>
> 754.1666

Answer (score 2):

Your query is wrong. It is typically like how you to aggregation on distributed system. You can do aggregation on distributed node, then bring back the aggregation data and do agg on top of you return data, only except for the aggregation is transferable. **AVG** is not transerable. (1+2+3+4+5)/5 <> ((1+2)/2 + (1+2+3)/3)

Answer (score 1):

```
with t1 as
(SELECT price, type from pc left join product on product.model = pc.model where maker = 'A'
UNION ALL
SELECT price, type from laptop left join product on product.model = laptop.model where maker = 'A')
select avg(price) from t1
```

Answer (score 1):

It also work

```sql
SELECT Avg(price) AS avg_price
FROM   (SELECT pc.price
        FROM   pc
               INNER JOIN product
                       ON pc.model = product.model
        WHERE  maker = 'A'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT laptop.price
        FROM   laptop
               INNER JOIN product
                       ON laptop.model = product.model
        WHERE  maker = 'A') Any_name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AVG(resultList.Price)
FROM
    (
        SELECT  a.Price
        FROM    PC a INNER JOIN Product B 
                    on a.Model = B.Model
        WHERE   B.Maker = 'A'
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  c.Price
        FROM    Laptop c INNER JOIN Product d 
                    on c.Model = d.Model
        WHERE   d.Maker = 'A'
    ) resultList
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select AVG(P.price) as avg_price
from
(
 select price, model from PC
 UNION ALL
 select price, model from Laptop
) P
join Product ON P.model = Product.model
where maker = 'A'
```

Comment: It would be better if you add some explanation here!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AVG(price) FROM 
(
     SELECT PC.price, Product.maker FROM PC JOIN Product ON(PC.model=Product.model)
     UNION ALL
     SELECT Laptop.price, Product.maker FROM Laptop JOIN Product ON (Laptop.model = Product.model)
) T 
GROUP BY T.maker HAVING T.maker = 'A'
```

It works because at first you select all laptop and pc prices, next you choose only records where maker = 'A', and the last step is counting an avg price.

Comment: You may consider adding some explanatory sentences, this increases the value of your code! So just an idea why this works.

Comment: It works because at first you select all laptop and pc prices, next you choose only records where maker = 'A', and the last step is counting an avg price.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select avg(price) from
       ((select price,model  from pc 
       union all
       select price,model from laptop) a inner join  product on product.model=a.model and product.maker='A' )
```

Firstly, I think that it would be better if I `union` `price` and `model` of both tables and afterwards we can find `average(price)` from maker A.

Answer (score 0):

I always have great struggle with JOINS(personally), so try this solution without joins.
using IN Operator

```
with cte as (
    SELECT price, model, code 
    FROM pc 
    WHERE model 
    IN (SELECT model FROM product WHERE maker = 'A')
UNION
    SELECT price, model, code 
    FROM laptop 
    WHERE model 
    IN (SELECT model FROM product WHERE maker = 'A')
)

SELECT AVG(price) FROM cte
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select avg(P.price) from 
(select pc.model as model,pc.price as price from PC pc 
union all 
select L.model as model,L.price as price from Laptop L ) P
where P.model in 
( select model from Product where maker = 'A' )
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

```
select avg(price) as avg_price from
(select price
from Product, PC
where Product.model = PC.model
and maker = 'A'
union all
select price
from Product, Laptop
where Product.model = Laptop.model
and maker='A') avg_price
```

Comment: A good answer describes what your code changes do. So please add some description to it.